# AWS Mythical Mysfits - Nomodule named flask - ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, flask

I am very new to aws and especially docker 
so I have been following this link to understand stuff about developing a web application - 
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-two/

I am stuck at the point where it asks us to test the service locally using a 'docker run' command(in module - 2)
when I run the command I am getting an 'ImportError'.

Here are my code-snippets ....please help me out !
mythicalMysfitsService.py -

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, Response, request
from flask_cors import CORS

# A very basic API created using Flask that has two possible routes for requests.

app = application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application)

# The service basepath has a short response just to ensure that healthchecks
# sent to the service root will receive a healthy response.
@app.route("/")
def healthCheckResponse():
    return jsonify({"message" : "Nothing here, used for health check. Try /mysfits instead."})

# The main API resource that the next version of the Mythical Mysfits website
# will utilize. It returns the data for all of the Mysfits to be displayed on
# the website.  Because we do not yet have any persistent storage available for
# our application, the mysfits are simply stored in a static JSON file. Which is
# read from the the filesystem, and directly used as the service response.
@app.route("/mysfits")
def getMysfits():

    # read the mysfits JSON from the listed file.
    response = Response(open("mysfits-response.json").read())

    # set the Content-Type header so that the browser is aware that the response
    # is formatted as JSON and our frontend JavaScript code is able to
    # appropriately parse the response.
    response.headers["Content-Type"]= "application/json"

    return response

# Run the service on the local server it has been deployed to,
# listening on port 8080.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo Updating existing packages, installing and upgrading python and pip.
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN echo Copying the Mythical Mysfits Flask service into a service directory.
COPY ./service /MythicalMysfitsService
WORKDIR /MythicalMysfitsService
RUN echo Installing Python packages listed in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN echo Starting python and starting the Flask service...
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["mythicalMysfitsService.py"]
```

docker build -

```
ec2-user:~/environment/aws-modern-application-workshop/module-2/app (python) $ docker build . -t 054166015944.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest
```

OUTPUT -

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/14 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 1d622ef86b13
Step 2/14 : RUN echo Updating existing packages, installing and upgrading python and pip.
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7cdaa818c9c2
Step 3/14 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a1fd46891d1e
Step 4/14 : RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f81dc75dfc3f
Step 5/14 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0cee88c88f43
Step 6/14 : RUN echo Copying the Mythical Mysfits Flask service into a service directory.
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 709b50aac794
Step 7/14 : COPY ./service /MythicalMysfitsService
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f70454638e83
Step 8/14 : WORKDIR /MythicalMysfitsService
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 418a08d8ac32
Step 9/14 : RUN echo Installing Python packages listed in requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03659d0cb00e
Step 10/14 : RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cb65480b6104
Step 11/14 : RUN echo Starting python and starting the Flask service...
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89738a63f437
Step 12/14 : ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 97b4f200a571
Step 13/14 : CMD ["mythicalMysfitsService.py"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a22fe5fb5bdb
Step 14/14 : RUN unset -v PYTHONPATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f43930d6410a
Successfully built f43930d6410a
Successfully tagged 054166015944.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest
```

docker run to test service locally -

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 054166015944.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest
```

error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mythicalMysfitsService.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, Response, request
ImportError: No module named flask
```

checked for flask using `flask --version`
OUTPUT -

```
Flask 1.0.4
Werkzeug 1.0.0
```

So I have 'flask' installed but it still says No module named flask.

Comment: Can you provide the full docker build output?

Comment: yes, I have edited it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using `ubuntu:latest` as base image is a bad idea. If you pulled a few months ago, you'd get Ubuntu 18.04. If you pulled today, you'd get Ubuntu 20.04. So it's possible to get inconsistent builds. Better to have a specific release as base image, e.g. `ubuntu:20.04`. Better yet, use `python:3.8-slim-buster` as the base image and you'll get latest Python 3.8 pre-installed on Debian, and can easily switch to 3.9 when it's out.
2. My guess is you installed libraries on Python 3 (`pip3 install`) but you're running the code with Python 2. Try switching ENTRYPOINT to `python3` instead of `python`.

This article talks more about choosing a good tag for your base image: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/reproducible-docker-builds-python/

Comment: suggestion 2 is good. It needs to use python3-pip and pip3 in different places.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your instruction and was able to get the flask app to run.

I would suggest that you delete the image that was built previously and build again. Delete the image using `docker rmi 054166015944.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest`.

If you get an error stating that the image is being referenced by a container, you'll have to delete the referenced containers using `docker rm <container id>` or run `docker rmi -f 054166015944.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest` to force the delete although referenced.

Comment: ya..i tried doing that too...it didn't work 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mythicalMysfitsService.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, Response, request
ImportError: No module named flask`

Comment: Yes you need to remove the previous docker as its badly configured

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this (It solved the same problem I have):

Update python at 4 places in the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo Updating existing packages, installing and upgrading python and pip.
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN echo Copying the Mythical Mysfits Flask service into a service directory.
COPY ./service /MythicalMysfitsService
WORKDIR /MythicalMysfitsService
RUN echo Installing Python packages listed in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN echo Starting python and starting the Flask service...
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["mythicalMysfitsService.py"]
```